# Add CodeMirror to Skulpt Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror, skulpt

I am making an online python editor. I am using Skulpt to run the code entered into the texarea by the user. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<textarea id="textbox" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
<br /> 
<button type="button" onclick="runit()">Run</button> 
<pre id="dynamicframe"></pre>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function builtinRead(x) {
    if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
        throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
    return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
}

function runit() {
    var prog = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    var mypre = document.getElementById("dynamicframe");
    mypre.innerHTML = '';
    Sk.pre = "output";
    Sk.configure({
        output: outf,
        read: builtinRead
    });
    (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'canvas';
    var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
        return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
    });
    myPromise.then(function(mod) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log(err.toString());
        });
}
```

I am new to CodeMirror, and I would like to use their python version to add code colouring, line numbering and indentation to my textarea, but I am a bit confused as to how I would go about changing my code to add these features, as I find their website a little vague on connecting their tool to textareas.

How can I use CodeMirror alongside my existing textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have added codemirror to highlight matching brackets in my textarea:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementByid('textbox'), {
                        mode: 'none',
                        matchBrackets: true,
                        dragDrop: false,
                        styleSelectedText: false,
                        showCursorWhenSelecting: true,
                        lineWrapping: true
                    });
var textAreaContents = editor.getDoc().getValue();
```

Thats all I had to do. You can tweak the configuration to tailor it e.g. setting the [mode](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/mode/) will  highlight and optionally smart-indent text in a specific programming language.

Here is the fiddle that shows codemirror setup in the python mode with lineNumbers and indentation: https://jsfiddle.net/gw0shwok/2/

Configuration options for Python are documented [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/mode/python/index.html)

Extra functionality is available via several [addons](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addons)

Comment: Can you try and change the code that I provided so that it runs alongside CodeMirror with line numbers, indentation etc

Comment: please may you help on this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061820/skulpt-runit-button-conflicting-with-codemirror) as it is not getting much attention