# Skulpt runit() button conflicting with CodeMirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror, skulpt

I am making an in-browser (static) Python editor with Skulpt and CodeMirror. Here is the code for it so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/mode/python/python.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <link href="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function outf(text) {
            var mypre = document.getElementById("dynamicframe");
            mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text;
        }

        function builtinRead(x) {
            if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
                throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
            return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
        }

        function runit() {
                var prog = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
                var mypre = document.getElementById("dynamicframe");
                mypre.innerHTML = '';
                Sk.pre = "dynamicframe";
                Sk.configure({
                    output: outf,
                    read: builtinRead
                });
                (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'canvas';
                var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
                    return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
                });
                myPromise.then(function(mod) {
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        console.log(err.toString());
                    });
            }
            //<![CDATA[
        window.onload = function() {
                CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('textbox'), {
                    mode: {
                        name: "python",
                        version: 2,
                        singleLineStringErrors: false
                    },
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    indentUnit: 4
                });
            } //]]>
    </script>
    <textarea id="textbox" name="textbox"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="runit()" type="button">Run</button>
    <pre id="dynamicframe"></pre>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

With the `<button>`, I call `onclick="runit()"` but it does not do anything at all when clicked. I took the skulpt code directly from their website ([skulpt.org](http://www.skulpt.org/)) and the CodeMirror parts from a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/gw0shwok/2/). They seem to conflict each other in some way when I call the `runit()` function on a button click. Why is this? How can I fix the issue?

A link to my live editor: http://ckdata.neocities.org/python.html

Comment: Try this please: Keep a ref to the codemirror editor i.e. `var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(...)` then use the code `var prog = editor.getDoc().getValue(); ` to get the contents of the textarea.

Comment: @Dhananjay nope that doesn't work at all. A link to my editor is here: http://ckdata.neocities.org/python.html

Comment: Worked for me: check this snapshot of the [output](https://s4.postimg.io/hvl11m3vx/Output.png) on my browser :

Comment: could you share a link to the changed code? it works if I put text inside the <textarea> tags but not if i type it in myself - and then it will only run if the default text is still inside the textarea

Comment: Added the changed code as an answer (since it was too long for a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
// Step 1: Declare a variable to hold the editor:
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var editor;
         function outf(text) {...
```

Then save the codemirror editor when it's created:

```
 // Step 2 : Save the codemirror object in the editor.
   window.onload = function() {
                editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('textbox'), {
                    mode: {...
```

Finally use the codemirror API to get the contents of the editor in the `runit` callback:

```
function runit() {
            var prog = editor.getDoc().getValue(); // Use codemirror API
            var mypre = document.getElementById("dynamicframe");
```

This worked for me: here is the [output](https://s4.postimg.io/hvl11m3vx/Output.png)

Here is the entire modified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/mode/python/python.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <link href="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var editor;
        function outf(text) {
            var mypre = document.getElementById("dynamicframe");
            mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text;
        }

        function builtinRead(x) {
            if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
                throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
            return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
        }

        function runit() {
                var prog = editor.getDoc().getValue();
                var mypre = document.getElementById("dynamicframe");
                mypre.innerHTML = '';
                Sk.pre = "dynamicframe";
                Sk.configure({
                    output: outf,
                    read: builtinRead
                });
                (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'canvas';
                var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
                    return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
                });
                myPromise.then(function(mod) {
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        console.log(err.toString());
                    });
            }
            //<![CDATA[
        window.onload = function() {
                editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('textbox'), {
                    mode: {
                        name: "python",
                        version: 2,
                        singleLineStringErrors: false
                    },
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    indentUnit: 4
                });
            } //]]>
    </script>
    <textarea id="textbox" name="textbox"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="runit()" type="button">Run</button>
    <pre id="dynamicframe"></pre>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, can you give an example page that combines your and my code?

Comment: Pasted it in the answer